# Camera module works on one but not on another

Tags: camera

Hopefully I have 2 RPi to test. I tried my camera module on one it doesn't work but it's fine on another. The one doesn't work just keep red LED on cam module in and either raspistill or raspivid hang without any image or video showing.

Anyone has idea how to check if it has H/W defect?
The failed RPi I can run anything without issue any problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have different gpu_mem settings for each Pi? The camera requires at least 128M to be specified.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run raspi-config and enable the camera?

You could try swapping the sdcard and the camera together to determine if it's a hw problem

Edit: If the LED is coming on and just staying on, it's likely to be a connection problem :(

Answer (score 0):

## sudo raspi-config

-- Enable Camera

Adds two lines to boot partition

## Required for RPi Camera

start_file=start_x.elf

fixup_file=fixup_x.elf

a. Lift tab around camera cable so its floppy

b. make sure camera cable is plugged in with blue side to Ethernet

c. Make sure cable is level/vertical when you push down tab.

---

## Try and split problem

Move Camera and SD to other pi, split problem from 3 possible SD/Camera/Board

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Raspbian as OS? If so, make sure you have the last update.

Also make sure you have enabled the camera with raspi-config.

If it still doesn't work, double-check that you put the camera into the camera socket the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Move **both** the **Camera And SD card** between **RPi A** and **RPi B** to **isolate h/w** and prove it is a H/W defect.

This **removes software config and OS issues** from the equation

This will Isolate the defect to only RPi hardware and **prove the fault lies in hardware.**